# Draw TextView with correct orientation on image returned by custom camera PictureCallback() method

Tags: android, android-camera

I am building a custom camera interface with a TextView that displays text over the screen while the user takes their picture. I want to save the users image with this text overlayed as the user saw it while they were taking the picture.

I have `mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);` set before starting the preview and everything looks great. But when I try to save this image the TextView drawn over it the image is ends up rotated 90 degrees from the text.

I'm not sure what the best way to account for this is.

Ideally I could just save the image returned by the preview which seems to have proper orientation.

Here is my callback:

```
PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
    Bitmap cameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    cameraBitmap = cameraBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Bitmap bmp = mTextView.getDrawingCache();
    Bitmap img = overlayImages(cameraBitmap, bmp);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);

    img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,90, fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
  }
```

With OverlayImages() defined as:

```
public Bitmap overlayImages(Bitmap background, Bitmap foreground) { 
    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(background);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(foreground, 0, 0, null);
    return background;
}
```

Any clue what the best approach is here? It seems there are a lot of gotchas with managing orientation. Many seem to involve saving the file and then checking the EXIF information.

This seems way more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

The picture taken is a Jpeg in "natural" camera orientation, which is usually landscape (even if the natural device orientation is portrait, as with Nexus 7 or many phones). You can use EXIF info to verify this angle, but actually you can do it once for any device. Note that [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) only works with files, so you have to (at least once) save the Jpeg data to disk before you can establish this angle for the device.

After that, you don't need to analyze EXIF info to know the true orientation of the picture that arrives to your callback. On most tablets it will be same orientation as you receive from your [OrientationEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html); on most phones it will be 90° off.

If your activity locks the screen orientation to portrait and this is the way it displays the text, and you want save the original image with text overlay exactly as the users see the screen just before they press the shutter button, you don't care about the true picture orientation. So simply rotate the image by 90° or by 0°, depending on the device.

If you want to save the picture in "natural" orientation with the text caption nicely aligned, you must use Orientation sensor and rotate both text and image.

I am not sure that your code above can produce a correct overlay, because the dimensions of the `cameraBitmap` and that of the `mTextView.getDrawingCache)` may not fit. You can scale the `camerBitmap` down to screen dimensions (which fits the text `bmp`), but you will not achieve good results if you scale the text up to match the `cameraBitmap`.

A better solution is to use a graphics library to overlay the text over image, e.g. [MeiaUtil](https://github.com/bkhall/AndroidMediaUtil). It can also be used to rotate the camera image losslessly in Jpeg format.